# Unix Command to grep a time range

Tags: linux, unix, solaris-10

I have a log file, saved with particular date. I wanna fetch log entries during a particular time and date range to another file.

Ex: all entries from
2014-12-04 00:00:00 time to 2014-12-04 17:00:00

Answer (score 4):

Try egrep:

```
pttrn="2014-12-04 0[0-9]"
pttrn="${pttrn}|2014-12-04 1[0-6]"
pttrn="${pttrn}|2014-12-04 17:00:00"

egrep "${pttrn}" <logfile>
```

The egrep pattern contains three parts.  The first part grabs everything from 00:00:00 to 09:59:59.  The second part grabs everything from 10:00:00 to 16:59:59, and the third part grabs 17:00:00.

Comment: Your first `egrep` eliminates values beginning with `08` or `09` (i.e., times between `08:00` and `09:59`), and the second one allows `17:10`, `17:20`, `17:30`, etc..., to get through.

Comment: @G-Man  Thanks.  You're right.  I think I've fixed it now.

Comment: That looks like it should work. It could be simplified to `egrep "2014-12-04 (0[0-9]|1[0-6]|17:00:00)"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want 4 minutes interval of logs,

```
grep "01/APR/2014:16:3[5-9]" logfile
```

will return all logs lines between 16:35 and 16:39 on 01/Apr/2014.

Suppose you need the last 5 days starting from 17/Sep/2014 you may use the following:

```
grep "1[3-7]/Sep/2011" logfile
```

Hopes this helps,

Answer (score 0):

You can select a starting line and an ending line with e.g. `sed`:

```
sed -n '/Dec  5 11:00/,/Dec  5 12:00/p' /var/log/daemon.log
```

This will print all lines from the first line with `Dec  5 11:00` up to (and including) the first line with `Dec  5 12:00`. This is assuming the log is time-sequential (i.e. all lines are in order of time). The `-n` is to suppress the default action of printing each line.

Comment: But this assumes that there are entries for `Dec  5 11:00` and `Dec  5 12:00`, doesn't it? If `Dec  5 10:59` is immediately followed by `Dec  5 11:01`, then `sed` won't know where to start. And if there is a `Dec  5 11:00`, but then `Dec  5 11:59` is followed by `Dec  5 12:01`, `sed` won't know where to stop.

Comment: True; you could leave out the `:00` part, but then again there would have to be at least one log line per hour. Personally I'd adapt the script to fit the data; perhaps even apply some perl foo.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above modifications in date range, one can search for intended strings in the same command line.

Example:

```
grep "Nov 30 18:" /var/log/maillog | grep "Remote_" | wc -l
```

Try increasing the search loops with adding more `|` or save the results in a file:

```
grep "1[3-7]/Sep/2011" /var/log/maillog > /var/krishna.txt
grep "1[3-7]/Sep/2011" /var/log/maillog > /tmp/results.txt
```

`*wc -l` counts the total in list generated from previous parts of the code.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are inside the directory where existingfile.log exists.

```
$ egrep "(2014-12-04 00:*|2014-12-04 17:00:00)" existingfile.log >> /home/newfile.txt
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).